# Django 1.2 - Pb with a form in a template (WSGIRequest)

Tags: django

I'm trying to display a form on a template, but I get a fantastic error :

> Caught AttributeError while rendering: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'get'

The error is in this line : {% for field in form.visible_fields %}

My view :

```
def view_discussion(request, discussion_id):
 discussion = get_object_or_404(Discussion, id=discussion_id)
 form = BaseMessageForm(request)

 return render(request,'ulule/discussions/view_discussion.html', {
  'discussion':discussion,
  'form':form,
 })
```

My form :

```
class BaseMessageForm(forms.Form):
 message_content = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())
```

My template :

```
<form action="" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
    {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
        <div class="fieldWrapper">
            {% if forloop.first %}
                {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
                {{ hidden }}
                {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}

            {{ field.errors }}
            {{ field.label_tag }}: {{ field }}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
    <p><input type="submit" value="Send message" /></p>
</form>
```

Thanks a lot for your help !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I remember correctly, the error you are getting happens because you got the signature of form's initializer wrong: the first argument to it is "data", which in your case resides in request.POST (and not the request itself), if you are arriving on a POST that is.

Commonly a view with a form will look something like this:

```
def my_view(request, ...):
    if request.method == 'POST': # The form has been submitted
        form = MyForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # do whatever you want here, save the form, etc
    else:
        form = MyForm()
    return render_to_response('myform.html', ... )
```

Comment: Happened to me all the time, to be honest (actually happens now too) :)

Comment: Just to clarify shylent's answer, it's the >> form = MyForm(request.POST) << part that needs to be double-checked. I for one was (mistakenly) doing >> form = MyForm(request) << which is wrong.